# How to see that existence non-trivial parallel $p$-form implies $b_p\geq 1$ using De Rham cohomology?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, de-rham-cohomology

Suppose $(M,g)$ be a (for simplicity consider closed) Riemannian manifold. Because every parallel $p$-form $\omega$ is harmonic so the $p$-th Betti number should be positive i.e. $b_p\geq 1$. How to see this using De Rham cohomology (of course without using properties of Hodge theory like $\delta$, 1-1 correspondence between De Rham and Harmonic forms, etc.)? It is well-known that parallel forms are closed. What is the next step?

Such an easy argument based on harmonic forms I think there must be similar easy argument based on De Rham cohomology or it needs somewhat difficult argument?

Comment: [cross-posted on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/386871/90655)

Answer (score -1):

You should read a reference on Hodge theory.

The conclusion is not hard, that the map $\mathcal H^k \to H^k_{dR}$ is injective (that is, that harmonic forms are closed and exact harmonic forms are zero). The hard part is arguing that this map is surjective.

---

> Lemma: A $p$-form is harmonic, $\Delta \alpha = 0$, if and only if $d \alpha = 0$ and $d^* \alpha = 0$.

Proof: Recall that $\Delta = \pm (d^* d + d d^*)$, where the sign depends on dimension of manifold and degree $p$ of the form. $$\langle \pm \Delta \alpha, \alpha \rangle = \langle d^* d \alpha, \alpha \rangle + \langle d d^* \alpha, \alpha \rangle = \langle d^* \alpha, d^*\alpha \rangle + \langle d\alpha, d\alpha \rangle = |d^*\alpha|^2 + |d\alpha|^2,$$ here using that $d^*$ is the $L^2$-adjoint of $d$; the inner product is $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle = \int \alpha \wedge *\beta$.

The RHS can only be zero if $d^* \alpha$ and $d\alpha$ are both zero. QED.

---

> Corollary: if $\alpha$ is an exact harmonic form, then $\alpha = 0$.

Proof: we know that $d^*\alpha = 0$. If $\alpha = d\beta$, it follows that $d^* d\beta = 0$. But then $$0 = \langle d^* d\beta, \beta \rangle = \langle d\beta, d\beta \rangle = |d\beta|^2,$$ so that $0 = d\beta = \alpha,$ as desired. The same argument shows that coexact harmonic forms ($\alpha = d^* \beta$) are also zero.

Comment: What is this? all above argument I have read before. this is not a valid answer though.

Comment: @C.F.G The corollary and its proof don't need anything about Hodge theory.  Rather, it is just a simple integration-by-parts argument: Any harmonic form on a closed manifold is orthogonal (with respect to the standard $L^2$-inner product) to the image of d, and in particular the only exact harmonic form is the trivial form.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @JeffreyCase: It uses harmonicity of form. this is not what I want.

Comment: @C.F.G The fact that a parallel form is harmonic is a trivial observation: The divergence of a form $\omega$ is (up to a sign) the trace of the covariant derivative of $\omega$, and hence any parallel form is also co-closed.  Hence a parallel form is orthogonal to the image of d, and you're done.  If you don't want to use this argument, please specify what is "hard" about this argument or what makes an argument "easy" for you.

Comment: @JeffreyCase: So you are using Hodge decomposition theorem? i.e. $\Omega^k=\ker\Delta\oplus d\Omega^{k-1}\oplus \delta \Omega^{k+1}$. also  co-closedness is about harmonic forms and exactness is about De Rham cohomology.

Comment: @C.F.G The proof given in this answer uses only the fact that the spaces $\ker\Delta$, $d\Omega^{k-1}$, and $\delta\Omega^{k+1}$ are mutually orthogonal.  It does not use the Hodge Decomposition Theorem; i.e. it does not require that the direct sum is equal to (rather than just a subset of) the space $\Omega^k$.